# jQuery find function with escape characters not working in latest version

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, xhtml

I have a selector in a find function that works with jQuery 3.3.1 and before that doesn't in 3.4.0 and 3.4.1. I am using it on an xhtml jQuery document object that I have used $.parseXML on. I am using the full version of jQuery.

I have looked into the jQuery changelogs and see nothing that should affect this, as well as in the source changes on github.

I have tested the find with .class and #id and it works, but the IDs will be dynamic so I need to search by attribute name. There will also be multiple spans that I need to manipulate which is why I need a .each(function). Currently we are freezing our dependency to jQuery 3.3.1 because it works as expected but in 3.4.0+ it doesn't even enter the function.

Works:

```js
const xmlDoc = $.parseXML(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
        <html xmlns:dd="DynamicDocumentation">
        <head>
        <title></title>
        </head><body><span dd:drop_list_uuid="9999">mydrop1</span></body></html>`);
const $xml = $(xmlDoc).find('body');
$xml.find('span[dd\\:drop_list_uuid]').each(function() { 
  console.log($(this).text())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Does not work:

```js
const xmlDoc = $.parseXML(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
        <html xmlns:dd="DynamicDocumentation">
        <head>
        <title></title>
        </head><body><span dd:drop_list_uuid="9999">mydrop1</span></body></html>`);
const $xml = $(xmlDoc).find('body');
$xml.find('span[dd\\:drop_list_uuid]').each(function() { // This is the line that doesn't work
  console.log($(this).text())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you xml string is not in quotes in your example

Comment: Sorry I'll fix this, this is not the case in the actual project.

Comment: Sorry I have added the entire header, I thought the minimum would work. namespace should be defined now

Comment: I have updated your question with [mcve] - you were missing </html> too

Comment: Thank you for that, I'm pretty new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved here. 3.4.0+ gets rid of sizzle.

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-find-function-with-escape-characters-not-working-in-latest-version#14737000008103091

"the new versions of jQuery use querySelectoAll without sizzle. So many sizzle syntaxes don't work anymore.

A namespaced attribute query was probably implemented in sizzle."
-jakecigar